# Need to flush host in mysql to make it accept requests again why?

Tags: mysql

so my mysql stops accepting connection requests (aka getting data from mysql) after a lot of errors caused by something in my game server, I don't know what it is and I don't know how to find it but when I do "mysqladmin flush-hosts -p" and enter password of-course, it gets fixed. Any idea what I should do?

Thanks,
Aditya

Comment: This question belongs to [sf].

Comment: But to answer your question: check the [flush statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/flush.html), and check the "HOSTS" buttet. If MySQL gets more that (by default) 100 errors, it will refuse further connections. You have to either fix those errors, or set the `max_connect_errors` server system variable to a high value. (Fixing the errors would of course be the best option here.)